# Redux not updating this.props in componentDidMount with async method

Tags: react-native, redux

My redux is not updating the props.

My component:

```
...
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getTenantByID, updateTenant } from '../actions';
...
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tenantData: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTenant();
  }

  onChangeText = (text, input) => {
    const obj = { ...this.state.tenantData };

    obj[input] = text;

    this.setState({
      tenantData: obj
    });
  };

  onChangeNumberFormat = (text, input) => {
    const obj = { ...this.state.tenantData };

    let value = parseFloat(text);
    if (isNaN(value)) {
      value = 0;
    }
    value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
    obj[input] = value;

    this.setState({
      tenantData: obj
    });
  };

  getTenant = async () => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const tenantID = navigation.getParam('tenantID', '0');
    await this.props.getTenantByID(tenantID); // Wait for action to complete
    this.setState({
      tenantData: this.props.tenantData
    });
  };
...
const mapStateToProps = ({ tenants }) => {
  const { error, tenantData, saving } = tenants;

  return { error, tenantData, saving };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getTenantByID, updateTenant
})(TenantDetails);
```

In my action, I export the method:

```
export const getTenantByID = ({ tenantID }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const getTenant = {
      FirstName: 'Jonh', LastName: 'Doe', Email: 'jonh@test.com', Phone: 'xxx-xxx-xxxx',
      Unit: '101', MiddleName: '', RentalAmount: '1000.50', MoveInDate: toDate('2019-01-01'),
      MoveOutDate: toDate('2019-12-01'), LeaseStartDate: toDate('2019-01-01'), LeaseEndDate: toDate('2019-12-01'),
    };
    dispatch({
      type: GET_TENANT_DATA,
      payload: getTenant
    });
  };
};
```

And I use the reducer to return the data.

```
...
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  error: false,
  data: [],
  tenantData: {},
  saving: false,
};
...
case GET_TENANT_DATA:
      return { ...state, error: false, tenantData: action.payload };
```

If I do a console.log in the GET_TENANT_DATA in my reducer, I can see that the action.payload has data. But if I do console.log(this.state.tenantData) in my render() method, it is empty. Why is it happening?

Thanks

I include logs in the componentDidMount and render. It display in the following order

```
call render
this.props.tenantData is empty
Call componentDidMount
this.props.tenantData is empty
call render
this.props.tenantData has value
call render
this.props.tenantData has value
```

It is never setting state.tenantData. Why is it calling render() after componentDidMount()?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here, in `getTenant` function.

1. `getTenant` should not be async function becuase you are not returning a promise

```
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
      if (prevProps.tenantData.Email !== this.props.tenantData.Email) {// you need a unique value to check for changes in props
         this.setTenantData();
       }
    }

   setTenantData = () => this.setState({ tenantData: this.props.tenantData });

    getTenant = () => {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        const tenantID = navigation.getParam('tenantID', '0');
        const tenantData = this.props.getTenantByID(tenantID); 
  };
```

And this should be your action.

```
export const getTenantByID = ({ tenantID }) => {
    const tenant = {
      FirstName: 'Jonh', LastName: 'Doe', Email: 'jonh@test.com', Phone: 'xxx-xxx-xxxx',
      Unit: '101', MiddleName: '', RentalAmount: '1000.50', MoveInDate: toDate('2019-01-01'),
      MoveOutDate: toDate('2019-12-01'), LeaseStartDate: toDate('2019-01-01'), LeaseEndDate: toDate('2019-12-01'),
    };

    return {
      type: GET_TENANT_DATA,
      payload: tenant
    };
};
```

So you can see tenantData under the `console.log` in `componentDidUpdate`.

And the reason for setState not working under `getTenant` is because the component takes time to update after the redux action

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what you mean by getTenant cannot be async, but it tried and it did NOT work. Leaving the code as I posted, if I navigate back and reopen the component, it works.

Comment: I updated the solution. I did not test the first time. But I did this time and it is working. Sorry about the first post.

I did not set to state, because it's a prop which will not change so no need to keep it in component state

Comment: And on this question `It is never setting state.tenantData. Why is it calling render() after componentDidMount()?` the component will render anytime the props changes. That is what we see under componentDidUpdate

Comment: So, how can I set the state with the props data? I can't set the state in the render() method.

Comment: why do you want to setState a prop to state? As far as I know, it's a value that will not change in the component so you can use that prop any where like this.props.tenantData. But if you still want to set it to state check the solution. Its been updated

Comment: Thank you. componentDidUpdate worked. I just called the this.getTenantID that I already have, I did not create a setTenantData(). I still don't know why getTenant can't be async. Could you please explain?

Comment: when the function you are calling is going to return a promise then you can use async/await. In this situation, you are dispatching a redux action so no async/await

Comment: But the method getTenantByID dispatch GET_TENANT_DATA

Comment: In other words, ones the `GET_TENANT_DATA` is dispatched and redux state is set, the component will update and componentDidUpdate will be called. you don't need to await on redux state changes.